# tensorflow distributed train worker process supervisor init twice

Tags: tensorflow, session, distributed

I'm trying to write distribued tensorflow program, But something odd for me, especially the multi-distributed-workers exported model predicted result almost 0.00003(max:0.000031, min:0.00000001, var:0.00001, mean: 0.00003, learning rate is 0.00125, model: logistic regression, sigmoid actvation as last), while it works fine when i use only one worker process(predicted result mean value: 0.478, var: 0.41, max: 0.999, min:0.00000001).

My Code structure as follows:

```
        with K.tf.device(
                K.tf.train.replica_device_setter(
                    ps_device="/job:servers",
                    worker_device="/job:%s/task:%d/cpu:0" % (
                        self.job_name + 's', self.train_id),
                    cluster=self.cluster)):
            self._build_model(self.job_name)
            self._build_data_pipeline(self.job_name, role=['train'])
            self._build_monitors(self.job_name)
            self._build_algo(self.job_name)
            self._build_summaries(self.job_name)
            self._build_save_model(self.job_name)
            self._build_train_conf(self.job_name)
        self._build_supervisor(self.job_name)
```

and my supervisor and managed_session codes as follows:

```
    logging.info('[is_chief] %s', is_chief)
    sv = K.tf.train.Supervisor(
        is_chief=is_chief,
        logdir=self.model_conf['export_dir'] + '/save',
        init_op=self.init_op,
        summary_op=self.summary_op,
        save_model_secs=0,
        save_summaries_secs=self.save_summaries_seconds,
        saver=self.saver,
        global_step=self.global_step)


    logging.info('sess target: %s', self.server.target)
    with sv.managed_session(
            master=self.server.target,
            config=threads_config,
            start_standard_services=False) as sess:
        sv.start_queue_runners(sess)

        do the training steps.
        when finished input data, export model manually.
```

but I found that master session occurred twice, what does it mean?

```
I 2017-04-11 08:59:38 framework.framework:3020 ============After build model==============
I 2017-04-11 08:59:38 framework.framework:3027 [is_chief] False
I 2017-04-11 08:59:38 framework.framework:2077 RUNTIME CHECKING ...
I 2017-04-11 08:59:38 framework.framework:2026 [CHECKER] ModelSize Checking ...
I 2017-04-11 08:59:38 framework.framework:2064 [CHECKER] GraphNotNone Checking ...
I 2017-04-11 08:59:38 framework.framework:2082 Runtime Checker result: True
I 2017-04-11 08:59:38 framework.framework:3094 sess target: b'grpc://localhost:15926'
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master_session.cc:928] Start master session 74d502743e860d45 with config:
use_per_session_threads: true

I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master_session.cc:928] Start master session 12114aca8d44d336 with config:
use_per_session_threads: true
```

Comment: Same problem with you. I guess there are problem with graph define.